# VBA: Using index/match within a for loop

Tags: vba

I have two columns of data and I'm trying to associate the two columns.  In one column I have a part number and in the next column I have a part description.  I want to return the part description.  I have written a for loop to go through everything.  I'm getting a subscript out of range error.

```
Sub findDataTest()

'define and set variables
Dim i As Integer
Dim returnRange As Range
Dim lookRange As Range
Dim startCell As Range

Set startCell = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A3:A459")

Set returnRange = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B3:B459")

Set lookRange = Sheets("Sheets3").Range("A3:A459")

'for loop to get values
For Each startCell In lookRange

    For i = 3 To 459

        Cells(i, 6).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(returnRange, WorksheetFunction.Match(startCell, lookRange, 0))

    Next i

Next startCell

End Sub


Part Numbers  Part Descriptions
111           nut
222           bolt
333           screw
444           flange
555           cover
```

The above is the master data where the part numbers and part descriptions are stored.

```
Part Number
111
444
222
111
333
222
222
```

The above is the data I'm working with where I need to match the part description with the part number listed.  I can have any combination of part numbers with each part number showing at various frequencies.

Comment: You are iterating through the very range you are trying to match.  If the numbers are unique it will return the value right next to the iteration basically giving you a copy of Column B.  Please mock up some data and expected outcome.

Comment: Part Number Part Description
111 nut 
222 bolt
333 screw
444 flange
555 cover
666 gear
777 button
888 widget
Say, what's above is the master data.

Part Number
111
555
111
444
777
222
777
888
This is the data for which I'm trying to match the part description.

I  have this Master worksheet which has all of the part numbers and part descriptions.  What I need to do is Index and Match the part descriptions and then use that to match the part descriptions to the data I'm working with.  This data could be any combination of part numbers with any frequency.

Comment: Not in the comments.  Please put the example and expected output in the original post using edit.

Comment: Do you need vba? A `vlookup` will work great in this instance.

Comment: maybe use "Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A"&i)" instead of "startcell" in the match function.

Comment: @ErinH. did you notice the answer I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is using a dictionary. To do that first you have to add Microsoft Scripting Runtime from Tools/References by checking the checkbox next to it.

In the example I assume that your part numbers are unique. Your descriptions can be duplicate, but it is better to be unique so you can find the part number using the description too.

Sheet1 contains your data. Sheet2 shows how the descriptions are populated.
I used columns A and B for both sheets, however you can change them based on your needs. These data can be on different Excel files (Workbooks) too.

To easily use this sub you can insert a shape and right click on it and assign a macro, find the sub and then you should be good.

Excel code and Example is attached. You can improve the code by taking from here ;)

You can download the file from here:
https://ufile.io/x8n0u

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindDescription()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    'Define data range
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lRow = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Make a dictionary [key=Part Number, item=Part Description]
    'Keys should be unique, so to avoid any error we will record only
    'the first instance in case there are part number duplicates
    On Error Resume Next 'will move on if there is any duplicate
    For i = 1 To lRow
        dict.Add WS.Cells(i, 1).Value, WS.Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Now we have the data, we need to populate the descriptions
    'find the last row in Sheet2
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lRow = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Clear column B regardless of finding a matching Part Desc or not
    For i = 1 To lRow
        If dict.Exists(WS.Cells(i, 1).Value) = True Then
            WS.Cells(i, 2).Value = dict(WS.Cells(i, 1).Value)
        Else
            WS.Cells(i, 2).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with dictionaries, I need to find a couple of tutorials on using them.

Comment: @ErinH. just read the quick start on this website. Dictionaries are very easy and useful: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the link, it's useful! :)

Comment: @ErinH. then please hit the check mark next to my answer to confirm you got the right answer